# Browser blocks CORS request although Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set correctly

Tags: cors

A Javascript developed by one of our suppliers needs to make a cross origin XMLHttpRequest request to a service in our company. The URL (obfuscated for security reason) for the GET request is basically sth like

```
https://infoservice.testcompany.com/ourservice/api/public/eventshash
```

Unfortunately the OPTIONS preflight for this request fails with an unexpected error (Firefox console):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://infoservice.testcompany.com/ourservice/api/public/eventshash. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
```

But, when I analyze the request, I can find exactly the header variable and value which has been complained about in the error message. Slightly obfuscated HAR output:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.1",
    "creator": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "62.0"
    },
    "browser": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "62.0"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2018-09-20T06:44:28.458+02:00",
        "id": "page_1",
        "title": "Main page - Home",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": -1,
          "onLoad": -1
        }
      }
    ],
    "entries": [
      {
        "pageref": "page_1",
        "startedDateTime": "2018-09-20T06:44:40.869+02:00",
        "request": {
          "bodySize": 0,
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "url": "https://infoservice.testcompany.com/ourservice/api/public/eventshash",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "infoservice.testcompany.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "de,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Request-Method",
              "value": "GET"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
              "value": "if-modified-since"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "https://mainpage.testcompany.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "queryString": [],
          "headersSize": 484
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Thu, 20 Sep 2018 04:44:40 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "private"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=10"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
              "value": "https://mainpage.testcompany.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
              "value": "true"
            },
            {
              "name": "Allow",
              "value": "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS"
            },
            {
              "name": "Vary",
              "value": "Origin"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
              "value": "Accept-Language"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
              "value": "if-modified-since"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
              "value": "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "de,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "close"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "application/json",
            "size": 0,
            "text": ""
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 504,
          "bodySize": 504
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 23,
          "dns": 0,
          "connect": 11,
          "ssl": 0,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 14,
          "receive": 0
        },
        "time": 48,
        "_securityState": "secure",
        "serverIPAddress": "192.168.0.1",
        "connection": "443"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I receive

```
{
    "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value": "https://mainpage.testcompany.com"
},
```

which should be correct.

In Apache I create the CORS headers as follows:

```
<Files eventshash>
ForceType application/json
# Not needed, saves time:
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# CORS:
SetEnvIf Origin "http.*\.testcompany\.com.*$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header Always Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header Append Vary Origin
Header Always Set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Accept-Language" env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "if-modified-since" env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS" env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header echo Accept-Language
</Files>
```

I can see the CORS blocking error in Firefox, IE11 and in Chrome. But I think my CORS headers are correct and I have absolutely no clue, what else could be missing in the webserver reply. Ah yes, I know that Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" is bad and therefore am not using it. Just to complete my input.

Any idea what could be missing / wrong?

cu, Steffen

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing and I'm so curious and nervous about the answer!!!

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when the server is not accepting request from other domains.

for eg: if my server is running on https://test.com and I'm making a get request to other server (https://test2.com) and the test2 server is not configured to accept other server requests then this kind of errors occurs.

In your case I think you are missing secure entry in apache files,

```
"http.*\.testcompany\.com.*$"
```

please change this to below

```
"https.*\.testcompany\.com.*$
```

Comment: Actualy http.* and https.* both match for `https://something`. So it should not make any difference. And if it wouldn't already match, the line

`Header Always Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin`

would not work. Anyway, I tried it right now and same result.